# Syntax error : Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsmutablearray

Hello I'm fresher in iOS development. 
Below is error that I'm getting :

> generate syntax error. error like as "Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2"

```
for (int i=1; arrParseRespnse.count; i++)
{
  [arruserName addObject:[[arrParseRespnse objectForKey:@"%@",i]objectForKey:@"userName"]];            
}
```

> error:Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2

Thanks.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What is `[arrParseRespnse objectForKey:@"%@",i]` supposed to be?

Comment: still same generate error  : i want get value from json and  code is : {
    1 =     {
        currentHeader = 0;
        emailid = "default@gmail.com";
        password = password;
        userId = 11;
        userName = defaultUser;
    };
    2 =     {
        currentHeader = 0;
        emailid = "sam@gmail.com";
        password = sam;
        userId = 12;
        userName = sam;
    };
    3 =     {
        currentHeader = 0;
        emailid = "amit@yahoo.com";
        password = amit;
        userId = 13;
        userName = amit;
    };
}

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be:

```
for (NSInteger i = 1; i <= arrParseRespnse.count; i++) {
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)i];
    [arruserName addObject:arrParseRespnse[key][@"userName"]];
}
```

Note the modern syntax and the proper building of your key from `i`.

Comment: Glad I could help. Feel free to close out the question by accepting the answer when you can.

Answer (score 0):

The part where you write

```
objectForKey:@"%@",i
```

Is incorrect. That method only takes one argument, but you are giving it 2.

Comment: get value from json:{
    1 =     {
        currentHeader = 0;
        emailid = "default@gmail.com";
        password = password;
        userId = 11;
        userName = defaultUser;
    };
    2 =     {
        currentHeader = 0;
        emailid = "sam@gmail.com";
        password = sam;
        userId = 12;
        userName = sam;
    };
    3 =     {
        currentHeader = 0;
        emailid = "amit@yahoo.com";
        password = amit;
        userId = 13;
        userName = amit;
    };
}